# Python 3: obtain struct.pack output that matches Python 2 struct.pack output

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-2.7, struct

In Python 2:

```
import struct
struct.pack('B', 21)[0] # returns '\x15'
```

In Python 3:

```
import struct
struct.pack('B', 21)[0] # returns 21
```

Is there some way to create the byte string returned by Python 2 in Python 3? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ooh, `chr(21)`!

Comment: This is an interesting question. In python 2, `pack` returns a string and each member of a string is a single character string. In python 3, `pack` quite sensibly returns a bytes array but individual members of a bytes array are ints < 256. Its a place where 2 to 3 conversion could break. By "member", I mean the value you get when you index an item.

Comment: Ya, I'm trying to convert a Python implementation of the original NES synthesizer (written in machine code) to Python 3 and there are lots of breaking changes in the handling of binary objects between Python 2 and 3!

Comment: At the python level, the result of `pack` is an opaque blob. You get the right stuff back when you unpack. When I wrote my comment I wasn't sure the use case of python ever touching a member of the blob. I'm still not sure I've got one.

Comment: It would bite you if you want to send data a byte at a time. `for b in data:myconnection.send(b)`.

Comment: *buh-dum-bump* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't index the byte string it returns:

```
>>> struct.pack('B', 21)
b'\x15'
```

Comment: @duhaime That's what you wrote, the first byte is 21. Clearly you are looking for something else.

Comment: @duhaime Are you looking for `hex(21)` or `"{:x}".format(21)`?

Comment: @duhaime Getting the hexadecimal representation of an integer as a string is a way different question that you originally asked though.

Comment: I cleaned up some of my comments but wanted to ask--this is a bytes data type, whereas Python 2 returns a string--can one get this object as a string type in Python 3? `chr(21)` returns the string that's needed

Comment: @duhaime I don't know what that means. Bytes and strings are quite different. You can try decoding the binary string as UTF-8 perhaps?

Comment: I just mean I need this function call to return '\x15', not b'\x15'

Comment: @duhaime That is not a valid string for all values you can give to the `struct.pack`. You will have to change the other code to work with bytes instead of strings.

Comment: In python 3, strings are unicode characters. I'm not sure how turning bytes or larger binary data (e.g., int), into code points is useful. For instance `"\x250"` is `'ú'` and its utf8 encoding is `b'\xc3\xba'`. In python 3, strings are not simply byte arrays.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right--I think I'll need to change the other internal code to work with bytes. RIP Python 2 ⚰️